# When submitting a form with POST method, 405 Error shows up

Tags: html, post, spotify

My project is to have a user input a name of an anime and it will call the Jikan API to give out a list of shows and also display the theme songs links with the Spotify API on a separate HTML file (search.html). However, when trying to submit the form, it will display the correct URL "{website}/**search.html**" but will give me a 405 error.  I'm using glitch.me to help host my website so I am able to see that the search.html works, but only when I type out the URL not when submitting the form.  When I use a GET request for the form, however, it will display the shows but the Spotify API will give an error ({"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"Invalid authorization code"}). It will still display the links from Spotify, but Im worried about that error.  I wondering whether it was because of the POST method or something with my code.

index.html

```
<form action="search.html" onsubmit="testJS()" method="POST" id="theFormID" class="input-wrapper">
    <button name="search" class="fa fa-search"></button>
    <input type="text" id="search" placeholder="Search for anime..." value="" minlength="3">
    <div class="fa fa-times" onclick="document.getElementById('search').value = ''"></div>
</form>
```

If you need to see more of my code let me know!

Comment: HTML file cannot accept **$_POST** request. You need to process your form with a server-side language.

Comment: @NcXNaV Ohh ok that makes sense! thank you